# Multiple columns in WHERE (Excel)

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to count if the columns `K`, `L`, `M`, `N`, `O`, `P`, `Q`, `R`, ... contains a string

My code:

```
=QUERY(Atividades!11:100; "SELECT count(A) where K ='"&$A$2&"' OR L ='"&$A$2&"' OR M ='"&$A$2&"' OR N ='"&$A$2&"'")
```

I wanna something like this:

```
 =QUERY(Atividades!11:100; "SELECT count(A) where K:Z ='"&$A$2&"')
```

It's a XLSX file in google drive. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Using query on XLSX file should work the same as a google sheet. To test if a range of columns contains a string, you could use something like this for the following sample data to return all rows with a `?` in any of the four columns. It retuns a list as concatenated cells that are separated by a mushroom .

```
=Query(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(trim(transpose(query(transpose(QUERY(A1:E,"Select * where A is not null")),,
COLUMNS(QUERY(A1:E,"Select * where A is not null")))))," ","")),"Select Col1 where Col1 contains '?'")
```

Sample

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple? | Ca | mask | Frog |
| Alpha | Wask | oh?no | Cow |
| Apple | ?? |  | Donkey |
| Echo | Trash | NOpe | Deer |
| Duke | Trash | Nope | Luke |
| Call | Trash | Trash | Han |
| Duke | Trash | Ca | Ca?st |
| Jump | Trash | Dink? | Came |
| Duke | Trash | Trash | Luke |
| Call | Trash | Trash | Han?? |
| ? | Trash | Trash | Cast |
| Jump | Trash | Dink? | Came |

[image]